# How to search in the whole linqdatasource while there's a control parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

There's two linqdatasource, one is bounded to a dropdownlist and another to a gridview. DropDownList is the control parameter. 
My code:

```
<asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ContextTypeName="TestPortalDataContext" EntityTypeName="" EnableUpdate="true" EnableDelete="True" 
    EnableInsert="True" TableName="AllSuitesWithFeatureNames" 
    Where="FeatureName==@FeatureName" OrderBy="SuiteID desc" OnSelecting="LinqDataSource1_Selecting">
    <WhereParameters>
     <asp:QueryStringParameter DefaultValue="" Name="SuiteID" QueryStringField="SuiteID" />  
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" DefaultValue="1" 
            Name="FeatureName" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="string" />
    </WhereParameters>
</asp:LinqDataSource>

<asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqDataSource2" runat="server" 
    ContextTypeName="TestPortalDataContext" EntityTypeName="" 
    TableName="AllFeatures" OrderBy="FeatureName">
</asp:LinqDataSource>

<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" CssClass="DDDropDown" 
    DataSourceID="LinqDataSource2" DataTextField="FeatureName" DataValueField="FeatureName" AutoPostBack="True" >
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Since there's a control parameter in LinqDataSource1, so each time I have to select the right FeatureName under dropdownlist to search. I know in sql it's easy to search in all table vale. But how can I search in all the LinqDataSource1 linq way?

Answer (score 0):

try this. assuming

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" CssClass="DDDropDown" 
DataSourceID="LinqDataSource2" DataTextField="FeatureName" DataValueField="FeatureName" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" >
```

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        LinqDataSource1.Where = "FeatureName==" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
        LinqDataSource1.DataBind();
        gridView.DataSource = LinqDataSource1;

        gridView.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" DefaultValue="1" Name="FeatureName" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="string" /> does the same thing - DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged,  in fact, DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged generates an error: Server Error in '/' Application.

No property or field 'OS' exists in type AllSuitesWithFeatureName'